# Inserting from python to MariaDB dynamic column (COLUMN_CREATE)

Tags: python, mariadb

MariaDB allows inserting name-value pairs in blob column using COLUMN_CREATE function inside INSERT 
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/dynamic-columns/

Example

```
CREATE TABLE T (id int, v blob);
INSERT INTO T (id,v) VALUES(1,  COLUMN_CREATE('color', 'blue', 'size', 'XL'));
```

I failed to do it from python:

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect (host=.., user=‘.., password=.., port=..,  database=..)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
SQL='INSERT INTO T (id,v ) VALUES(%s,COLUMN_CREATE(%s))'
data=[(10,'"X",2'),(20,'"Y",1')] # <---- I think problem is here
cursor.executemany(SQL,data)
cursor.close()
cnx.commit()
cnx.close()
```

I got an error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
>   ')),(20,COLUMN_CREATE('\"Y\",1'))' at line 1

From the error message above I see what \ (backslash) was inserted automatically (by driver?)

How to pass data to Maria's COLUMN_CREATE function to make it work? 
I tried to change the single and double quotes: it did not help.

Comment: What happens in Python when a structure like `data` is formatted via "%s"?

Comment: This package solves the issue: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mariadb-dyncol

It converts the python dictionary to internal MariaDB dynamic column format

Comment: If so, then provide that as the Answer to your Question.   (It is ok to self-Answer.)

Answer (score 0):

This package solves the issue:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mariadb-dyncol

It converts the python dictionary to internal MariaDB dynamic column format